# What is the equation of line that passes through two points ??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Th equation of a straight line that passes through point A(mid point (2,3) and (-8,15) )and point B (that lies 1/3 way from (-1,0) to (4,11) is given by ??

actually I am confused!!

calculated the mid-point of A = (-3,9)
 but now what how to proceed from now As B (lies 1/3 way from (-1,0) to (4,11)) i.e means another point I must it C .

Comment: what are the coordinates of $C$?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the second point $B$ is the point that has distance $1/3$ from $(-1,0)$ in the direction of $(4,11)$. If so, $B$ is the endpoint of the vector $(5,11)$ renormalized to have length $1/3$ applied in $(-1,0)$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner (-1,0) to (4,11)

Comment: @AndreaMori what does it mean by this line" A(mid point (2,3) and (-8,15) )"

Comment: @rAm Are you asking me? You even computed it!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

If point $\;P=(x,y)\;$ divides the segment of line with end points $\;A=(a_1,a_2)\;,\;\;B=(b_1,b_2)\;$ in the ratio $\;k:m\;$ , meaning:

$$\frac{|AP|}{|PA|}=\frac km$$

then the coordinates of $\;P\;$ are given by

$$\begin{cases}x=\frac{kb_1+ma_1}{k+m}\\{}\\y=\frac{kb_2+ma_2}{k+m}\end{cases}$$

Comment: i didnt understand

Comment: @rAm, what **exactly** you didn't understand? The first part is just a restatement of the *definition* of "ratio", whereas the second part gives you the formula to calculate the coordinates of a point dividing a line segment in a certain ratio (which I suppose you should have studied by now).